# Add 'images' and thumbnails to wordpress posts programatically

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I imported some of my data from a custom cms to WP. Now there are around 3000 articles, with 1 image attached to each. My sql import has put this image path as a custom field 'images' which has the path for the image with each 'post_id'.
 Now to make WP recognize this image as the one attached to the post, what should I do? (I think I need to make an entry in wp_posts table, but not sure about it)
please help..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$postId = 5; // for your case, article id
$imageId = 5;

wp_update_post(array(
    'ID'           => $imageId,
    'post_parent'  => $postId
));
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didnt' notice well you question. you have to create post by your image. because wordpress keep image in post table as post_type 'attachment', To create attachment please see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment